# Supervisord event listener to spiecific list of programs or group at docker container

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, environment-variables, supervisord

Mb someone could help me.

I'm trying to run supervisord at docker container to start php-fpm and nginx with wordpress. I want to configure wp-config.php file with envsubs which called from script. Additionally i want to follow docker way and kill supervisord with eventlistener if any of subprocesess falling. But when I execute this script on docker run it returns 0 code which event listener detect as  PROCESS_STATE_EXITED. Probably I could use eventlistener for specified list of programs with defined list of events or something like this?

Thanks.

````
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:cfg]
command=bash /usr/src/wordpress/config-prep.sh
startsecs = 0
autorestart = false
startretries = 1
priority = 1


[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm7.4
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
priority=2

[program:nginx]
command=nginx
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
priority=3


[eventlistener:x]
command=bash /etc/supervisor/stop-supervisor.sh
events=PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED, PROCESS_STATE_FATAL, PROCESS_STATE_STOPPING, PROCESS_STATE_UNKNOWN
priority=4```
````

Comment: Typical practice would be to run these processes in separate containers.  You'd be able to restart each process separately (using `docker` commands), supervisord wouldn't swallow their logs, and you can configure a restart policy via Docker.

Comment: Planned to run this on ecs + fargate at AWS. It putted to single container to manipulate containers with help of task defenitions and rolling update with AWS resources. Ofc i could add spiecific healthchecks on aws side. Also i spent too much time reading documentation of supervisord and i must be sure that I didnt missed anything. Somth like mapping to eventlistener spiecific group or somth like that.